# Alignment Issues With Headers

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I am having trouble with my alignment issues for my headers on my website,

http://questdesign.com.au/index.php/folio

Here is the code for my Folio page.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/quest_design_folio_web_header.png" alt="" width="954" height="51" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="985">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_websites_subheader.png" alt="" width="895" height="45" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="981">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/headers/quest_design_allison_driscoll_author_ebook_website.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_allison_driscoll_author_ebook_website.jpg" alt="" width="144" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_ironmonger_heavy_metal_rock_music_website.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_ironmonger_heavy_metal_rock_music_website.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_website.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_website.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_silence_no_more_music_website.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_silence_no_more_music_website.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="180" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="983">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/quest_design_folio_social_media_subheader.png" alt="" width="895" height="45" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="984">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_emmerson_legal_social_media_branding.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_emmerson_legal_social_media_branding.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="89" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_social_media_branding.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_social_media_branding.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="89" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_lifestyle_maximiser_social_media_branding.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_lifestyle_maximiser_social_media_branding.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="85" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_rock_solid_personal_training_social_media_branding.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_rock_solid_personal_training_social_media_branding.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="85" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="982">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/quest_design_folio_online_marketing_material_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="982">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_adam_quinn_social_media_marketing.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_adam_quinn_social_media_marketing.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="97" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_allison_driscoll_author_ebook_social_media_marketing.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_allison_driscoll_author_ebook_social_media_marketing.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="122" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_emmerson_legal_social_media_marketing.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_emmerson_legal_social_media_marketing.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="113" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_social_media_marketing.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_social_media_marketing.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="135" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/quest_design_folio_design_header.png" alt="" width="954" height="51" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="981">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_logos_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="981">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_australian_academy_kung_fu_logo.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_australian_academy_kung_fu_logo.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="141" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_kettlebell_strength_logo.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kettlebell_strength_logo.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_rawgasm_logo.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_rawgasm_logo.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="57" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_rock_solid_personal_training_logo.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_rock_solid_personal_training_logo.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="90" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="979">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_business_cards_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="978">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_emmerson_legal_business_card.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_emmerson_legal_business_card.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="110" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_mickyfit_training_business_card.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_mickyfit_training_business_card.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="110" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_rawgasm_business_card.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_rawgasm_business_card.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="110" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_rock_solid_personal_training_business_card.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_rock_solid_personal_training_business_card.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="110" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="980">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_flyers_brochures_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="979">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="images/quest_design_emmerson_legal_flyer.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_emmerson_legal_flyer.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="85" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_fifth_dimension_music_rave_flyer.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_fifth_dimension_music_rave_flyer.jpg" alt="" width="85" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_flyer.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_flyer.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="85" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_rawgasm_flyer.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_rawgasm_flyer.jpg" alt="" width="85" height="180" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="979">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_book_covers_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="979">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_beginners_guide_to_bodybuilding_book_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_beginners_guide_to_bodybuilding_book_cover.jpg" alt="" width="124" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_blades_of_the_fae_book_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_blades_of_the_fae_book_cover.jpg" alt="" width="127" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_carpentry_bible_book_cover.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_carpentry_bible_book_cover.jpg" alt="" width="127" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_drifter_book_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_drifter_book_cover.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="180" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="979">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_album_covers_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="978">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_earth_rhythm_album_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_earth_rhythm_album_cover.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_glasgow_kiss_album_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_glasgow_kiss_album_cover.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_ironmonger_album_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_ironmonger_album_cover.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_sarah_cooper_album_cover.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_sarah_cooper_album_cover.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="978">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_posters_banners_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="978">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_adam_quinn_music_promotional_poster.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_adam_quinn_music_promotional_poster.jpg" alt="" width="119" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_bitten_by_productions_beyond_babylon_theatre_poster.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_bitten_by_productions_beyond_babylon_theatre_poster.jpg" alt="" width="127" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_ironmonger_heavy_metal_music_promotional_poster.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_ironmonger_heavy_metal_music_promotional_poster.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="127" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_mickyfit_training_boot_camp_fitness_poster.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_mickyfit_training_boot_camp_fitness_poster.jpg" alt="" width="127" height="180" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="977">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_stationary_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="976">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_emmerson_legal_stationery.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_emmerson_legal_stationery.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="98" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_letterhead_stationery.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_letterhead_stationery.jpg" alt="" width="127" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_membership_card_stationery.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_kate_brock_personal_trainer_membership_card_stationery.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="102" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/rawgasm_stationary_example_quest_design.png" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/rawgasm_stationary_example_quest_design.jpg" alt="" width="127" height="180" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/quest_design_folio_image_header.png" alt="" width="954" height="51" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="983">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_retouching_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="982">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_luke_glamour_retouching.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images//headers/quest_design_luke_glamour_retouching.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="135" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_matt_monica_glamour_retouching.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_matt_monica_glamour_retouching.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="117" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_monica_glamour_retouching.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_monica_glamour_retouching.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="105" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_tegan_glamour_retouching.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_tegan_glamour_retouching.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="135" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="981">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/quest_design_folio_restoration_subheader.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 23px;" width="979">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_family_image_restoration.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_family_image_restoration.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="180" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_little_girl_image_restoration.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_little_girl_image_restoration.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="131" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_soldier_image_restoration.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_soldier_image_restoration.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="128" /></a></td>
<td><a href="images/quest_design_toddler_image_restoration.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is fourth image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://www.questdesign.com.au/images/headers/quest_design_toddler_image_restoration.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="56" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
```

Any chance you can let me know what I might have missed out on. They show up centered on Mozilla firefox but in Chrome it aligns more to the right hand side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change width: 982px; **TO** width="100%".

You can refer attached image.

[image]

If you want more details on what width: 100% do, you can refer this link :-
http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Chrome is setting the `width=985px`, as per the attribute on the HTML element, whereas Safari (and Firefox) are respecting the `max-width: 100%` (960) value in the CSS. Remove that attribute to fix!